# openFrameworks & Kinect: Improve human contour

Tags: c++, kinect, openframeworks

I am playing around with Kinect and I'm trying to get an as accurate as possible human contour.

So far I tried changing threshold values, blurring, etc... but I was wondering if there was an existing effective method of doing it.

I believe there are two main problems in order to get a good shape. One is that if keeps flickering all the time. The other, how is not a very good shape (hair not reflecting IR lighting, etc...).

Any reccomendations on how to proceed? At the moment I'm trying to average values of the most recent frames to stabilize for the first problem and I might try to convert the shape to a polygon and simplify it (however that's done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to improve the depth mask with a forground/background mask calculated from the RGB image and a classic background removal algorithm.

You could also work with the morphology functions of opencv to remove unwanted small parts of the mask or close holes.[1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#morphology-2)